# Weather/Bike riding method assistance needed

Tags: java

I am currently starting a Java course and am a relative beginner, I have been given an exercise one part of which asks me to write a method that prints out whether or not it is good enough weather to go on a bike ride. 
It must be greater than 40 degrees and less than 100 degrees unless it is raining in which case it must be greater than 70 degrees and less than 110 degrees.

The problem is that I am way more of a beginner (to programming in general) than most others on the course, and this exercise seems like a step up from the rest of the same assignment.

E.g the previous task, to create a dice rolling method -

```
public static int diceAverage (int pNumberofRolls) {
    int total=0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int loopy=1; loopy<=pNumberofRolls; loopy++){
        total = total + rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }
}
```

Sorry if formatting is off, I am on my mobile.

Comment: ask one question and provide code related to that question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try to learn coding. Don't post your assignments here.

Comment: If one of the solutions worked for you, please accept one answer to close the question

Answer (score 2):

Kyle's answer is good. For academic purpose, the same code with ternary operator:

```
public static boolean bikeOrNot (int temp, boolean rain) {
    return rain 
           ? temp > 70 && temp < 110
           : temp > 40 && temp < 100;
}
```

Few explanations:

- I'm using boolean instead of Boolean because the answer should not be null. Same thing for the argument *boolean rain* instead of *Boolean rain*. For that point, you can check the **primtive data type** concept
- **ternary operator** is a shortcut for `if ... then ... else...` written in one line: `(condition) ? (return this if condition is true) : (return this if condition is false)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
public static Boolean bikeOrNot (int temp, Boolean rain) {
    // check for rain
    if (rain){
        if (temp > 70 && temp < 110){
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        if (temp > 40 && temp < 100){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Call this like:

```
Boolean shouldIBike = bikeOrNot(60, false);
```

It checks if its raining, then checks the temperate and does the same if its not raining. If it doesn't fall into any `if`, it will reach the last line and return false, in that case, you should not go cycling.

Comment: all those Boolean objects should be replaced with boolean primitives.